# Why is my temperature values on my raspberry pi in the 700 range?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, grovepi+

My code is of this [temperature humidity sensor](https://www.dexterindustries.com/shop/temp-humidity/) that I attached to the grovepi sensor which is connected to the raspberry pi sensor. If possible could you inform me on how I could convert it to degrees Celsius. Thanks

```
import grovepi

sensor = 4

while True:
  try:
     [temp,humidity] = grovepi.dht(sensor,1)
     print "temp=", temp, "humidity =", humidity
  except IOError:
     print "Error"
```

[image]

Comment: what kind of sensor is that? looks like you need to convert those value

Comment: It is the temperature humidity sensor under dexter industries https://www.dexterindustries.com/shop/temp-humidity/

Answer (score 0):

It is a blue sensor so it should be `[temp,humidity] = grovepi.dht(sensor,0)`.

You could find it in source code [here](https://github.com/DexterInd/GrovePi/blob/master/Software/Python/grove_dht_pro_filter/grove_dht.py#L47) and [here](https://github.com/DexterInd/GrovePi/blob/master/Software/Python/grove_dht_pro_filter/grove_dht.py#L162)